# PHP Good search engine for checkout items

Tags: php, mysql, performance, search, keyword

I am making a checkout/cashier software as hobby project, at the moment I am trying to come up with some way to search items in the database.

I got a database from my part-time job which contains about 50,000 items of computer related parts and I want to be able to search through them using keywords or EAN code.

**If I enter this it shows the item**
[image: If I enter this it shows the item]

**If I enter this it doesn't show the item**
[image]

Am I doing something wrong in my MySQL Query?
This is how I come up with these results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE EAN LIKE '%" . addslashes($_GET['sTerm']) . "%' 
OR itemName LIKE '%" . addslashes($_GET['sTerm']) . "%' 
OR factoryId LIKE '%" . addslashes($_GET['sTerm']) . "%' 
OR itemId LIKE '%" . addslashes($_GET['sTerm']) . "%';
```

Where addslashes($_GET['sTerm']) stands for the search bar contents so in this case `AAA` or from the second image `AAA Varta`

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for pointing this out. I have already had a look at that although even if I do implement a fix at this point for that it wouldn't fix my issue of poor search results.

Comment: It might, as you wont have to use addslashes() and potentially alter your search terms in the process

Comment: Note: you are missing a closing `"` at the end of this line `OR itemId LIKE '%" . addslashes($_GET['sTerm']) . "%';`

Comment: Look into elasticsearch

Comment: Check that the white space between the words is identical in the table as in the query.  Use `HEX(...)` to help verify.

Comment: Consider `FULLTEXT` indexing -- a lot faster, but is limited to "words".